# Laravel strange error: Eloquent model changes into an instance of Builder class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4.2. And I have this strange error.

All I'm trying to do is pass this object of `User` (`Eloquent` model) to the method `scopeSendTo` of `EmailVerification` model; and came across this strange error which I can't figure out.

Here's my code:

```
class EmailVerification extends Eloquent
{
    ...
    public function scopeSendTo(User $user, $type)
    {
        $token = Str::slug(microtime(true).Hash::make(Str::random(20)));

        $verification = new EmailVerification([
            'token' => $token,
            'type' => $type,
        ]);

        $user->verifications()->save($verification);

        Mail::send('emails.verification', ['verification' => $verification], function ($message) {

            $name = $user->profile ? $user->profile->first_name : '';

            $message->to($user->email, $name)->subject('Account Verification');

        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I'm trying to use this method like this:

```
$user = User::find($userId);

EmailVerification::sendTo($user, 'signup');
```

But it throws this error:

[image]

I even tried doing `dd(get_class($user))` which confirms that the object passed is an `User` object and strictly not an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`; but I can't figure out what is the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) are helpful for reusing query logic in models. This means that the first parameter that gets passed to the scope method is a query builder instance , which can be manipulated and returned to allow for method chaining. In your case the scope method definition should look like this:

```
public function scopeSendTo($query, User $user, $type)
{
    // code goes here
}
```

While the code above will work, it's a bad approach, since that's not the intended purpose of scopes for Eloquent models.

I suggest revising your strategy for solving this problem. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18485217/351330) gives some good advice on implementing email verification using Laravel's integrated authentication service, or you can  consider using a more robust authentication solution such as [Confide](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide).